# What is the Google Cloud platform equivalent to a Digital Ocean Droplet?

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, digital-ocean

What is the Google Cloud platform equivalent to a Digital Ocean Droplet? Is it a Compute engine? or can a Compute Engine have multiple 'droplets'?

If I have 10 droplets on Digital Ocean each with their own VM and IP address, how do I achieve the same setup in Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Droplet" is just silly marketing speak for what is actually a virtual machine. It's probably best to avoid the term, even when referring to Digital Ocean.

Google actually refers to them as virtual machines or virtual machine instances, though they frequently abbreviate it to "VM".

Answer (score 1):

Droplet is same as Google Compute engine VM(VPS). differences are cost, performance and availability. Digital Ocean may have slightly better prices but less feature.

You can check VM benchmarks [here](https://www.vpsbenchmarks.com/compare/docean_vs_gce). also you can check review - https://stackshare.io/stackups/digitalocean-vs-google-compute-engine

And choose right for your fit.